# how can i add select query result into dataset later again select query run

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

i want to add select query result into dataset, so i can write new query to run on it to get net dataset but how?

**Original query:**

```
MyDATASET=(
select x, y,z from table1
union all
select k,l,m from table2
)
i wan to this select * from this.MyDATASET
```

Comment: updated answer to illustrate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could perhaps create a CTE, UDF or view? But it really isn't clear what you are trying to do...

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
    select x, y,z from table1
    union all
    select k,l,m from table2
GO

SELECT * FROM MyView
SELECT * FROM MyView WHERE x = 0
```

etc

Comment: I think a VIEW is probably what the OP is after.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to cache data for re-use later...

Use a temp table or table variable if it's contained within one bit of code.

If you want to refer the same data in several processes or calls, then use a temp table. Use a local one for many calls but don't close the connecion, use a global one for many different processes/connections.

If it's just one big select where you want to re-use the same data, then use a CTE.

A view also works but the data may change between executions.